# How backend https server connect with WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, ssl-certificate, wso2-api-manager

So I have https server and I want to make API with this server as back end. What I did was I copied certificate of server pem file and it converted into jks file and save it in 
`<APIMHome>/repository/resources/security` But I couldn't make API in this way. What else should I do make this work ?

this is how convert pem into jks

```
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias wso2carbon -file myserver.pem -keystore server.jks -storepass wso2carbon
```

Comment: What is the error you got ?

Comment: Here is the problem. After https server is up I export certificate as test.cer and add it into wso2carbon.jks using this command. 
     **keytool -import -keystore wso2carbon.jks -file test.cer**     then I tried to create API while it ask to test end point url it says invalid (:

Comment: You can provide the error stack

Comment: @user1574779 You have to import your certificate into client-truststore.jks file, not to wso2carbon.jks. Check my answer

Comment: Yeap what's the your problem now

Answer (score 0):

Trusted certificates have to be imported to client truststore.

eg: keytool ­importcert ­alias clientas ­keystore client-truststore.jks ­­file clientas.crt

Answer (score 0):

A certificate is a public key with extra properties (like company name, country,...) that is signed by some Certificate Authority(CA) that garants that the attached properties are true.

Convert you pem file into cer file with

```
openssl x509 -inform PEM -in myserver.pem -outform DER -out certificate.cer
```

Then import your certificate into wso2 client-truststore.jks resides in `wso2am-1.7.0/repository/resources/security` directory

```
keytool -importcert -file certificate.cer -keystore client-truststore.jks -alias "Alias"
```

Comment: Just a note for those using a default installation that the password for the key store is wso2carbon. This password is publicly available so no need to worry about me posting it here. Production deployments change this password as part of the process.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to install the certificate to trust store of the apimanger
2. after installing that if you get error as
   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Host name verification failed for host :

you might get this error seince hostname verification is set to Default. so to overcome this , modify the axis2.xml(https - transportSender) to turn Hostname Verification off as below.

`<parameter name="HostnameVerifier">AllowAll</paramete`r>